# "24 hours after mailbox activation" vs "after 24 hours of mailbox activation"

Tags: sentence-structure

In sentences given below. Which sentence’s structure is correct?

> 1) Communicator will be active **24 hours after** mailbox activation.

Or

> 2) Communicator will be active **after 24 hours of** mailbox activation.

Please give a justification, if possible.

Comment: It would be better if you started by explaining which *you* think is correct, & why; rather than the other way round.

Comment: both are okay, no major problem. go for either of them! :)

Comment: @MaulikV Well, the second is technically grammatical, but it's kind of hilarious semantically.  It's pretty unlikely to be what the OP (or anyone else) wants to say.

Comment: @Tetsujin, in first shot, I thought that second one is correct but later I realized that first one is much clear than second one

Comment: To make sentence #1 even clearer, you could say "become" instead of "be" -- as long as Communicator is inactive until that point.  But if it becomes active at some time *during* the first 24 hours following mailbox activation, you could say:  *Communicator will become active within 24 hours after mailbox activation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"... after 24 hours of mailbox activation" means that the activation is going on for 24 hours. That's probably not what you mean. It probably doesn't take 24 hours of work to activate a mailbox. I think what you mean is that the mailbox is activated, and then 24 hours later "Communicator" is active. In that case, the first sentence is correct. Mailbox activation is a one-time event taking a relatively short amount of time. Then 24 hours later Communicator is active.

I'm assuming here that "Communicator" is the proper name of some software product, and that this "thing" becomes active at a specific point in time. If that's not true, the sentence has other problems.

Comment: You understood correctly. In which context/situation, second one we can use (... after 24 hours of mailbox activation)

Comment: You should use "after 24 hours of ..." in a situation where the process goes on for 24 hours or more. Like, "The lubricant should be replaced after 24 hours of continuous operation."

Answer (score 0):

No sorry. The second is NOT correct. The first is Ok but would be better with "The communicator.....................

Comment: Wrong.  Both are correct given that Communicator is a proper noun.

Comment: @Chenmunka: How does the fact that Communicator is a proper noun have anything to do with the temporal issue that is central to the question?